# Create a DNS NSRecord

Tags: dns, bind

My server is a Ubuntu, and I have installed webmin/virtualmin and I´m trying to create my NSRecord ns1 and ns2.

I run this command:

```
dig @localhost mydomain.info
```

```
;  DiG 9.7.3  @localhost mydomain.info
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; HEADER opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64570
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.info.              IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.info.       38400   IN      A       10.28.166.120

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mydomain.info.       38400   IN      NS      ns1.mydomain.info.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.mydomain.info.   38400   IN      A       10.28.166.120
```

But 10.28.166.120 it´s my local IP, I try to find any information on /var/log/syslog about Bind and I didn´t see anything.

In Firewall I configured the ports like this:

```
Incoming open ports:

TCP/53 
UDP/53

Outgoing open ports:

TCP/53
UDP/53
TCP/1024-65535
UDP/1024-65535
```

So, know I put my complete dns record:

```
$ttl 38400
@   IN  SOA ns1.mydomain.info. root.ns1.mydomain.info. (
            1342267814
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
@   IN  NS  ns1.mydomain.info.
mydomain.info.  IN  A   10.28.166.120
www.mydomain.info.  IN  A   10.28.166.120
ftp.mydomain.info.  IN  A   10.28.166.120
m.mydomain.info.    IN  A   10.28.166.120
ns1.mydomain.info.  IN  A   999.999.999.999
localhost.mydomain.info.    IN  A   127.0.0.1
webmail.mydomain.info.  IN  A   10.28.166.120
admin.mydomain.info.    IN  A   10.28.166.120
mydomain.info.  IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:mydomain.info ip4:10.28.166.120 ?all"

999.999.999.999 = my external IP
```

I´m tried post some questions like this and anyone help on other forums. If anyone don´t undestand something I will try to explain.

Thank´s.

Answer (score 0):

BIND runs as `named`, so that is what you should look for in the logs. (Though nothing is actually wrong with this setup, so I doubt there would be anything in the logs).

I'm not sure how you've set up the records in your zone, but each `NS` record points to an `A` record. The NS record looks fine, but the A record is wrong. The other NS record and/or its corresponding A record are missing. You will have to change the A record for `ns1.mydomain.info.` to your external address. There is no simple way to use both an internal and external IP for a single machine (for a complicated way, see split-horizon views).

Comment: Ok, I change my A record for ns1.mydomain.info. and I can see named on syslog when I change my dns records. But it didn´t worked, What I need to do on my domain provider to be correct?

Comment: You need to supply both NS and A records to your provider. This is called a glue record: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records
However, if your IP is private, this isn't going to work properly. You A record must be a public IP address.